# Turn a bi-dimensional matrix into perl hash

Tags: perl, matrix, hash

I have a genotype matrix in which:

- Rows represent locus
- Columns represent samples
- Each value represents a genotype which could be either P1/P1, P2/P2, P1/P2 or NA if the genotype is not determined.

I'd like to turn this matrix into a perl HoH in order to get the genotype (specific then to the single sample and its locus).

My matrix looks like:

```
CDS             BC1-III     BC1-IV      BC10-II     
LOC105031928    P1/P2       P1/P2      P1/P2    
LOC105031930    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031931    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031933    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031934    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031935    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031937    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031938    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1
```

As an output, the code should give:

```
$hash{$sample}{$locus} = P1/P1 #(for locus LOC105031935 in sample BC10-II for example)
```

Here's what i've tried to solve the problem but I cant figure out yet how to assign in the hash each locus of the first column as a second key of this hashtable. @sample_names is a list of the three samples.

```
open(GENOTYPE, '<', "$matrix_geno") or die ("Cannot open $matrix_geno\n");
my %hash;
while (my $line = <GENOTYPE>) 
{

    my @columns = split(/\s+/, $line);
    @hash{@sample_names} = @columns;
    #print Dumper \%hash;
}
```

Any help will be seriously welcomed.

PS: This example is a small part of my data. I'm actually seeking for a more general solution

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code to show, then Stack Overflow might not be the best place to ask this question.

Comment: Please also include the sample output.

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, i just completed my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper;

my $matrix_geno = 'input.io';

open ( my $GENOTYPE, '<', "$matrix_geno" ) or die ($!);

my $header = <$GENOTYPE>;
chomp($header);

my @headers = split( /\s+/, $header );

my %hash = ();

while ( my $line = <$GENOTYPE> ) {
    chomp($line);

    my @columns_data = split( /\s+/, $line );

    $hash{$columns_data[0]}{$headers[1]} = $columns_data[1];
    $hash{$columns_data[0]}{$headers[2]} = $columns_data[2];
    $hash{$columns_data[0]}{$headers[3]} = $columns_data[3];

}

print Dumper(\%hash);

close($GENOTYPE);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'LOC105031933' => {
                              'BC1-III' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC10-II' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC1-IV' => 'P1/P1'
                            },
          'LOC105031934' => {
                              'BC1-III' => 'NA',
                              'BC10-II' => 'NA',
                              'BC1-IV' => 'NA'
                            },
          'LOC105031938' => {
                              'BC1-IV' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC1-III' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC10-II' => 'P1/P1'
                            },
          'LOC105031931' => {
                              'BC10-II' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC1-III' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC1-IV' => 'P1/P1'
                            },
          'LOC105031937' => {
                              'BC1-IV' => 'NA',
                              'BC10-II' => 'NA',
                              'BC1-III' => 'NA'
                            },
          'LOC105031935' => {
                              'BC1-III' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC10-II' => 'P1/P1',
                              'BC1-IV' => 'P1/P1'
                            },
          'LOC105031928' => {
                              'BC1-IV' => 'P1/P2',
                              'BC10-II' => 'P1/P2',
                              'BC1-III' => 'P1/P2'
                            },
          'LOC105031930' => {
                              'BC1-III' => 'NA',
                              'BC10-II' => 'NA',
                              'BC1-IV' => 'NA'
                            }
        };
```

Is this is the output you wanted?

Hope this helps and please change it your need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It'n very kind. I tried to rub this code with the command but it doesn't recognize the variable $RFH. Is their a specific module that i should load before ?

Thanks.

Comment: @AmyNdy: Looks like `$RFH` is a typo. It should be `$GENOTYPE`.

Comment: Yup, Sorry, Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks guys. You both just saved a perl beginner's life !

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want. I'm reading from `DATA` for simplicity.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

# Read headers
chomp(my $headers = <DATA>);
my @samples = split /\s+/, $headers;
# Remove 'CDS'
shift @samples;

my %genotype;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($locus, @genotypes) = split;
  for my $x (0 .. $#samples) {
    $genotype{$samples[$x]}{$locus} = $genotypes[$x];
  }
}

# Display the data structure
say Dumper \%genotype;

# Simple test
say $genotype{'BC10-II'}{LOC105031935};

__DATA__
CDS             BC1-III     BC1-IV      BC10-II     
LOC105031928    P1/P2       P1/P2      P1/P2    
LOC105031930    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031931    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031933    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031934    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031935    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1    
LOC105031937    NA          NA         NA   
LOC105031938    P1/P1       P1/P1      P1/P1
```

The output is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'BC10-II' => {
                         'LOC105031931' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031935' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031930' => 'NA',
                         'LOC105031928' => 'P1/P2',
                         'LOC105031937' => 'NA',
                         'LOC105031938' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031933' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031934' => 'NA'
                       },
          'BC1-IV' => {
                        'LOC105031934' => 'NA',
                        'LOC105031933' => 'P1/P1',
                        'LOC105031938' => 'P1/P1',
                        'LOC105031937' => 'NA',
                        'LOC105031928' => 'P1/P2',
                        'LOC105031930' => 'NA',
                        'LOC105031935' => 'P1/P1',
                        'LOC105031931' => 'P1/P1'
                      },
          'BC1-III' => {
                         'LOC105031931' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031935' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031930' => 'NA',
                         'LOC105031928' => 'P1/P2',
                         'LOC105031937' => 'NA',
                         'LOC105031938' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031933' => 'P1/P1',
                         'LOC105031934' => 'NA'
                       }
        };

P1/P1
```

Comment: Thank you @Dave Cross. With little modification to adapt with my perl script it gave me exactly what I needed.